# Get total hours from datatime mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a MySQL table where driver login and logout timings are recorded. Here in the Status column connected-represents login and disconnect-represents logout.

```
[id]   [User_id]           [Date_time]                 [status]
1       1          2011-01-20 09:30:03                  connect
2       2          2011-01-20 11:30:43                  connect
3       2          2011-01-20 11:45:12                  disconnect
4       1          2011-01-20 12:59:56                  disconnect
5       3          2011-01-20 13:33:11                  connect
6       3          2011-01-20 15:38:16                  disconnect
7       1          2011-01-20 15:46:23                  connect
8       1          2011-01-20 17:42:45                  disconnect
```

Is it possible to retrieve total hours worked in a day by a user using single query?

I tried a a lot but all in vain. I can do this in PHP using array but unable to do so using single query.

Comment: It looks like this has been answered on db.stackexchange (should probably be on this board?) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129898/total-hours-worked-per-employee-per-day

Comment: no buddy total time when they join to current day i mean total hours for user 1

Comment: Does anyone work past midnight?